# Unable to install apache2

Tags: server, software-installation, apache2, services, software-uninstall

I am trying to reinstall (through `apt`) `apache2` service on Ubuntu server, after it was removed it, but without any success. To be more specific the installation process finishes without any errors but

1. The service **never starts**,

```
$ systemctl start apache2
$ systemctl status apache2
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2020-11-30 17:15:08 CET; 11s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 18754 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 18747 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 30 17:15:08 www systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Nov 30 17:15:08 www systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
```

2. I noticed **missing files**, like `/usr/sbin/apache2` and /usr/lib/apache2.
   In fact,

```
$ whereis apache2
apache2: /etc/apache2 /usr/share/apache2
```

How can I install the service properly?

**Edit:**

```
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mo 2020-11-30 17:40:45 CET; 29s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 20855 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 30 17:40:45 www apache2[20855]:  *
Nov 30 17:40:45 www apache2[20855]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Nov 30 17:40:45 www apache2[20855]: Output of config test was:
Nov 30 17:40:45 www apache2[20855]: apache2: Syntax error on line 219 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 29 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf: Expected </XVirtualHost> but saw </VirtualHost>
Nov 30 17:40:45 www apache2[20855]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Nov 30 17:40:45 www apache2[20855]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Nov 30 17:40:45 www systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 30 17:40:45 www systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 30 17:40:45 www systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 30 17:40:45 www systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Also,

```
Nov 30 14:51:34 www systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 30 16:25:00 www systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 30 16:25:00 www systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Nov 30 16:25:00 www systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 30 16:25:53 www systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 30 16:25:53 www systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Nov 30 16:25:53 www systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 30 16:32:42 www systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 30 16:38:02 www systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 30 16:39:21 www systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Nov 30 16:39:21 www systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 30 17:15:08 www systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Nov 30 17:15:08 www systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 30 17:39:32 www systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 30 17:39:51 www systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Nov 30 17:39:51 www apache2[20730]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Nov 30 17:39:51 www apache2[20730]:  *
Nov 30 17:39:51 www apache2[20730]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Nov 30 17:39:51 www apache2[20730]: Output of config test was:
Nov 30 17:39:51 www apache2[20730]: apache2: Syntax error on line 219 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 29 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf: Expected </XVirtualHost> but saw </Virt
Nov 30 17:39:51 www apache2[20730]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Nov 30 17:39:51 www apache2[20730]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Nov 30 17:39:51 www systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 30 17:39:51 www systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 30 17:39:51 www systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 30 17:39:51 www systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 30 17:40:16 www systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Nov 30 17:40:16 www apache2[20830]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Nov 30 17:40:16 www apache2[20830]:  *
Nov 30 17:40:16 www apache2[20830]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Nov 30 17:40:16 www apache2[20830]: Output of config test was:
Nov 30 17:40:16 www apache2[20830]: apache2: Syntax error on line 219 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 29 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf: Expected </XVirtualHost> but saw </Virt
Nov 30 17:40:16 www apache2[20830]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Nov 30 17:40:16 www apache2[20830]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Nov 30 17:40:16 www systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 30 17:40:16 www systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 30 17:40:16 www systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 30 17:40:16 www systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 30 17:40:45 www systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Nov 30 17:40:45 www apache2[20855]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Nov 30 17:40:45 www apache2[20855]:  *
Nov 30 17:40:45 www apache2[20855]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Nov 30 17:40:45 www apache2[20855]: Output of config test was:
Nov 30 17:40:45 www apache2[20855]: apache2: Syntax error on line 219 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 29 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf: Expected </XVirtualHost> but saw </Virt
Nov 30 17:40:45 www apache2[20855]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Nov 30 17:40:45 www apache2[20855]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Nov 30 17:40:45 www systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 30 17:40:45 www systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 30 17:40:45 www systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 30 17:40:45 www systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: It sounds like your system has been fubar'd because the `apache2` executable got reassigned to a directory.  I think you may need to purge all Apache items and config first, and then do some cleanup.  Does `sudo apt purge apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data` and `sudo apt install apache2` in that order do anything?  (note that `purge` will remove all configuration items too, so make a copy of any configs you want to keep first in a separate directory.)

Comment: It did @ThomasWard, I have the missing files, but unfortunatelly I still can't run the service. I am addind the output of `systemctl status apache2` and `journalctl -xe` to the question...

Comment: Actually I will not paste the second command's result because its 1450 lines!

Comment: *that* error is a configuration-is-incorrect issue.  `apache2: Syntax error on line 219 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 29 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf: Expected </XVirtualHost> but saw </VirtualHost>`  Include the contents of the config file.  Also, are you using a customized APache2 installation / compilation?

Comment: Include the output of `journalctl -n 50 -u apache2.service` then specifically.

Comment: Included @ThomasWard

Comment: I use *plesk*, is there any chance it messes with the apache service?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116820/discussion-between-thomas-ward-and-themelis).